# Acquisition of Standard visa for British Army Assessment

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, ghanaian-citizens

I am employed as a contract staff in a financial institution in Ghana and have an invite from the British Army to come for assessment. I have a sister legally resident in the UK. My monthly commission ranges from Ghs 1000 to Ghs 3000 a month. I manage my deceased mum's business with a bank balance around Ghs 150000. I have the backing of my HR with a leave letter from them and also stating my job is secured even if I'm not successful with the army. Do I stand a chance to obtain a standard visa?

Comment: Unfortunately, this forum is for specific questions that have factual answers - we can't answer "what chance do I have" type questions, as only the immigration officer handling your case has access to all the details of your application.

Comment: Onua Ghanaman, we have hundreds of British army assessment questions like yours here. You can use the search button to find them. Short answer is, your chances are very slim.

Comment: Use the search box (at the top of each SE:Travel page) for "British Army Assessment." A list of previous questions on this subject will be returned. User56513 is correct: the quality of a good army candidate, and the quality of a good candidate for a UK visa, are in conflict, which makes a visa for assessment purposes very difficult to obtain.